# Gunicorn stuck at Booting worker with pid: 9293

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to implement nginx + django + gunicorn for my project deployment. I am taking the help of following article:
http://tutos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/ndg.html . I followed the steps as described. Now, I am trying to start gunicorn. What am I getting at the screen is:

```
$ gunicorn ourcase.wsgi:application
[2016-05-19 19:24:25 +0000] [9290] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.5.0
[2016-05-19 19:24:25 +0000] [9290] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9290)
[2016-05-19 19:24:25 +0000] [9290] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-05-19 19:24:25 +0000] [9293] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9293
```

Since, I am new to `nginx` & `gunicorn`, I am not sure whether the above is an error or not. I am getting nothing in error log

```
cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

It prints nothing on the screen. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That output means that the process is running. Which is what you want. You should try accessing the URL from the browser directly after running the command without pressing `ctrl+c`.

As a side note you can write a bash script to do this which will make it easier to add arguments to the gunicorn commands.

I have a gist that does just that. https://gist.github.com/marcusshepp/129c822e2065e20122d8

Let me know what other questions you might have and I'll add a comment.

Comment: Quite confusing, really. The message implies that it has not booted yet.